# Corrupted Textures with OpenGL 4.1 on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl

I am trying to draw textures with OpenGL 4.1 shader language.
It works absolutely fine on Windows, so I'm quite positive there is no problem in shader or coordinates.
On Mac, However, the textures are corrupted like on the picture:



[image]



If you'll notice - there are two small textures looks ok. The unique about them is that one is 16 and second is 32 pixels wide (Power of 2). Therefore it must be something in configuration or pixel storage. It can't be that textures which are not power of 2 are not supported, since they were on legacy openGL context (Not GLSL). Here is example of my texture generating:

```
    unsigned char* pixels = convertedImage->m_pixelbufs.at(0);
    GLuint imageDepth = convertedImage->GetBitsPerPixel() == 24 ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, convertedImage->GetWidth(), convertedImage->GetHeight(), 0, imageDepth, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, GL_FALSE);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_LSB_FIRST, GL_FALSE);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I tried to play with other glPixelStorei parameters but textures were always corrupted. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the other place. There was an old piece of code checking the extension **GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two** before actually extracting PNG file into memory and acting accordingly. On windows, despite the fact that it was moved to core answer was - **TRUE**, therefore behavior was as expected. On mac, since it moved to cere the answer was - **FALSE**, so the behavior was wrong.